# Quebra de linha automática com regex

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho a seguinte string: `$var = "Saudi Arabia U23 x South Korea U23";`
eu quero dividir os nomes que estão separados por `"x"`, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
$arr = preg_split('/[v|x]/', $var);
```

Usei `"V e X"` porque as vezes a string pode vim com um "v" separando os nomes, e não o X, o problema é que se tiver um "x" ou "v" incluído no nome, sem ser o "x" ou o "v" da separação, ele vai cortar também, mas eu só quero separas os nomes delimitado por `" x "` ou `" v "`.
Como faria isso no regex?

Comment: Isso é logicamente impossível. Tem como você mudar o separador usando caracteres que não aparecem no nome?, por exemplo com -(Hífen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta colocar espaços seguido de **+** fora do colchetes:

```
$arr = preg_split('/ +[v|x] +/', $var);
```

Essa regex vai remover os caracteres **" x "**, **" v "** e também os que tiverem mais de um espaço como **"   x  "** e **" v    "**

Comment: Perfeito! era isso que não tava sabendo fazer. obrigado!

Comment: Sua regex permite que o pipe seja um delimitador, ele dentro de uma lista perde sua funcionalide de `OU`/`OR` lógico.

Answer (score 1):

Essa regex resolve o problema, ela busca por um ou mais espaços seguido de um `v` ou `x` seguido de um ou mais espaços.

```
$str = 'abc X edfxct';
$arr = preg_split('/\s+v|x\s+/i', $str);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc 
    [1] => edfxct
)
```

Comment: Muito bom! obrigado pela ajuda